# Visiting Profile without open URL with CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I have a list of profile URL's which I want to 'shadow visit' without opening the URL's.
I thought I can send something to the websites server but actually I could not find any solution for that other than opening each URL but this takes forever with more than 13k URL's and it is lagging too.

I use CefSharp and have opened the Website and I'm logged in.

Any ideas?

Comment: `HttpClient` with concurrency + some HTML parser e.g. HtmlAgilityPack or AngleSharp. But you can't visit a page without opening the url as you can't read the file contents without opening it.

Comment: [This code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1178026/373567) (Russian StackOverflow) may help.